# How to create JSON object using jQuery

Tags: json, arrays

I have a JSON object in below format:

```
temp:[
        {
           test:'test 1',
           testData:  [ 
                       {testName: 'do',testId:''}
                         ],
           testRcd:'value'                             
        },
        {
            test:'test 2',
           testData:  [
                            {testName: 'do1',testId:''}
                         ],
           testRcd:'value'                           
        }
      ],
```

How can i create JSON object in jquery for above format. I want to create a dynamic JSON object.

Answer (score 218):

Just put your data into an Object like this:

```
var myObject = new Object();
myObject.name = "John";
myObject.age = 12;
myObject.pets = ["cat", "dog"];
```

Afterwards stringify it via:

```
var myString = JSON.stringify(myObject);
```

You don't need jQuery for this. It's pure JS.

Comment: Is it poosible to create index name dynamically. for ex: var name = $('#myname').val();
myObject.name = "john" //here name index will be dinamaclly from an input box.

Comment: A bump for the above comment: To replace any of the static values such as `.name` `.age` or `.pets` just replace that, including the dot, with a variable wrapped in square brackets. Example: `myObject[cssProp] = cssVal;` Then whatever the values of those two css variables are will be used in the Object. Here is a jsFiddle: [http://fiddle.jshell.net/arttronics/rucjtbza/](http://fiddle.jshell.net/arttronics/rucjtbza/)

Answer (score 30):

A "JSON object" doesn't make sense : [JSON](http://www.json.org/) is an exchange format based on the structure of Javascript object declaration.

If you want to convert your javascript object to a json string, use `JSON.stringify(yourObject)`;

If you want to create a javascript object, simply do it like this :

```
var yourObject = {
          test:'test 1',
          testData: [ 
                {testName: 'do',testId:''}
          ],
          testRcd:'value'   
};
```

Comment: @guillaumealgis, can you explain your roll back to my edit?  If you run the object through [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) it's flagged as invalid (the left hand keys needs to be double quoted).  I'm not arguing that you're wrong, I want to learn why you believe it's valid JSON because it may be something I don't understand.  If you run my version through the same validator it comes back as valid JSON.

Comment: @delliottg Don't use a JSON validator to validate JavaScript. Please read the start of my answer again.

Comment: @delliottg I'm not saying it's a valid JSON. The point of this answer is to differentiate JSON an JS object. Try running dystroy code in a JS interpreter and you'll see that it runs just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I realized I had a fundamental misunderstanding of how this stuff worked after reading through this again, and asking my own question about a project I'm working on.  I'm pretty sure I understand now, and thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 5):

I believe he is asking to write the new json to a directory. You will need some Javascript *and* PHP. So, to piggy back off the other answers:

script.js

```
var yourObject = {
  test:'test 1',
  testData: [ 
    {testName: 'do',testId:''}
   ],
   testRcd:'value'   
};
var myString = 'newData='+JSON.stringify(yourObject);  //converts json to string and prepends the POST variable name
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "buildJson.php", //the name and location of your php file
   data: myString,      //add the converted json string to a document.
   success: function() {alert('sucess');} //just to make sure it got to this point.
});
return false;  //prevents the page from reloading. this helps if you want to bind this whole process to a click event.
```

buildJson.php

```
<?php
    $file = "data.json";  //name and location of json file. if the file doesn't exist, it   will be created with this name

    $fh = fopen($file, 'a');  //'a' will append the data to the end of the file. there are other arguemnts for fopen that might help you a little more. google 'fopen php'.

    $new_data = $_POST["newData"]; //put POST data from ajax request in a variable

    fwrite($fh, $new_data);  //write the data with fwrite

    fclose($fh);  //close the dile
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

How to get append input field value as json like

```
temp:[
        {
           test:'test 1',
           testData:  [ 
                       {testName: 'do',testId:''}
                         ],
           testRcd:'value'                             
        },
        {
            test:'test 2',
           testData:  [
                            {testName: 'do1',testId:''}
                         ],
           testRcd:'value'                           
        }
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested `JSON` object

```
var data = {
        view:{
            type: 'success', note:'Updated successfully',
        },
    };
```

You can parse this `data.view.type` and `data.view.note`

`JSON` Object and inside Array

```
var data = {
          view: [ 
                {type: 'success', note:'updated successfully'}
          ],  
     };
```

You can parse this `data.view[0].type` and `data.view[0].note`

Answer (score -1):

```
var model = {"Id": "xx", "Name":"Ravi"};
$.ajax({    url: 'test/set',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: model,
                        success: function (res) {
                            if (res != null) {
                                alert("done.");
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (res) {

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: That's nice but the question doesn't involve C# or ASP

Comment: @Machavity, where do you find c# in this?

Comment: That comment was about the first revision of your answer, which had C# in it. Now it makes even less sense, as you're hardcoding the `model` variable. This question is: _"In JavaScript, how can I create an object at runtime and represent that object in JSON notation"_, which your answer still does not show.