# Formatting jQuery key/value separator

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, which successfully outputs data to to the product_slides array.

```
var product_slides = new Array();

Product.findAll({}, function(products) {
    $.each(products, function(i, product) {
        var product_slide = new Object();
        product_slide.title = product.name;
        product_slide.url = product.url;
        product_slides[i] = product_slide;
    });
});
```

When I view the contents with `console.log(product_slides);` in firebug's console it has the following format:

```
[
    {image = 'value', url = 'value'},
    ...
]
```

however, I need it to have the following:

```
[
    {image : 'value', url : 'value'},
    ...
]
```

which I believe may be JSON(?).

I'm still quite new to scripting, does anyone know how to swap those =s for :s ?

Comment: When you view _what_ contents? It is completely unclear which part of your code could produce the output you're giving.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The Firebug output is just informational, it's not intended for machine use.

Comment: Follow the guidance here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078324/how-to-create-json-object-using-jquery

Comment: Sorry - I missed the console.log - see the edit. Thanks Jay, I'll take a close look.

Comment: What you are looking at and logging is a javascript array containing javascript objects. JSON is the string representation of that data which you can create by following the link provided by Jay.

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your each, after making product_slide an object rather than an array

```
product_slide{'image':product.name, 'url':product_url};
```

If that works replace the hardcoded vals for keys

Comment: Thanks for the idea - unfortunately it doesn't like it at all.