# Passing data from a form to JSON-like objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

my form looks like:

```
<form name="input">

name: <input type="text" id="name">

data1: <input type="text" id="data1" value=110>
data2: <input type="text" id="data2" value=2 >
data3: <input type="text" id="data2" value=3>
data4: <input type="text" id="data2" value=4>


<input onclick="return inject();" type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

and my source code looks likes:

```
var plotting()=[
{height:data_1, weight:54 },
{height:data_2, weight:66 },
{height:data_3, weight:45 },
{height:data_4, weight:60 }
]
```

Let's say I would like to pass my variable data1 with height,

so I created a method

```
function injection(){
var data_1 = = document.getElementById("data1").value;
     .
     .
//repetition the first variable and method up to data4

}
```

It is not working but Can I just put data_1 in the Object like the above?
When I click submit it should update the variable.

Comment: Weight is hard coded or you want to update from textbox?

Comment: This may help you ::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078324/how-to-create-json-object-using-jquery

Comment: Weight is will be updated but before that, I want to test height first if it is working.

Comment: You could at least show _syntactically correct_ code, and code that doesn't have glaring inconsistencies. For example, `inject()` vs `injection()`, `= =`, `var plotting()` and these random `.` characters. Please put more care and attention into your questions.

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to copy and paste my whole code, So, I re-wrote it again. I will ask with well-arranged question form.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but here's a quick example on updating an object on form submit. This is half of the task if you wish to populate the form with the same data. You may have created that already.

```
<form id="demo">
    name: <input type="text" name="name">
    data1: <input type="text" name="data1" value="110">
    data2: <input type="text" name="data2" value="2" >
    data3: <input type="text" name="data3" value="3">
    data4: <input type="text" name="data4" value="4">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

```
var plotting = {};

// Update object on form submit
document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    var i = 0;
    while(e.target[i]) {
        var input = e.target[i];
        if(input.type != 'submit' && input.name) {
           plotting[input.name] = input.value;
        }
        i++;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

**Demo**:
http://jsfiddle.net/YaVzw/1/